# Get current date string for special format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am writing iPhone app now.
I want to get current date and time as following format.

```
Thu, 18 Apr 2013 01:41:13
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you make any effort to use `NSDateFormatter`? What have you tried?

Comment: Of course, I tried with NSDateFormatter. But how can I get string for Month and Weekday?

Comment: Post what you have so far so people can help with the missing parts.

Comment: BTW - did you read the docs for `NSDateFormatter` - specifically the part of specifying a date format? There is a link to all of the possible format specifiers so you get exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately I cannot find a way.

Comment: As I said, post (update your question) what you have so far and you will get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `setDateFormat:` in the *NSDateFormatter Class Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBEDIHH) links to the [*Data Formatting Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000029i).

In the *Data Formatting Guide*, the [Date Formatters > Use Format Strings to Specify Custom Formats > Fixed Formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13) section links to [Appendix F of the *Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Appendix F, while somewhat obtuse, tells you everything:

- Use `E` for the short week day name.
- Use `d` for the day of the month.
- Use `MMM` for the short month name.
- Use `y` for the year.
- Use `hh` for the hour.
- Use `mm` for the minute.
- Use `ss` for the second.

We can quickly test this without writing a whole Objective-C program using Python's Cocoa bindings:

```
:; python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Cocoa import *
>>> f = NSDateFormatter.new()         
>>> f.setDateFormat_('E, d MMM y hh:mm:ss')
>>> f.stringFromDate_(NSDate.new())
u'Wed, 17 Apr 2013 10:40:25'
```

In Objective-C, it looks like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [NSDateFormatter new];
f.dateFormat = @"E, d MMM y hh:mm:ss";
NSLog(@"%@", [f stringFromDate:[NSDate new]]);
```

Note that it is expensive to create an `NSDateFormatter`.  You should create it once and keep it around if you will be formatting many dates.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works to me. You are so kindness!

Comment: One more question for this. My phone region format is not US,so I can get non-US style dateformat string. But I needed US style date. How can I get this?

Comment: Look at the documentation of `-[NSDateFormatter setLocale:]` method.  Follow the link to `NSLocale`.  Read.